# Is the HTML5 code correct?

Tags: html5

I'm on a project involving converting HTML code to HTML5, and I'd like some feedback as to whether my code is correct or not.

Here's my stripped-down code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title Goes Here</title>
<!--[if IE 9]>
<script src="/jsp/fileFolderPath/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jsp/fileFolderPath/css/global.css">

<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->

<script src="/jsp/fileFolderPath/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jsp/fileFolderPath/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script src="/jsp/fileFolderPath/js/tip.js"></script>
<script src="/jsp/fileFolderPath/js/jquery.calendar.js"></script>

<script src="/jsp/fileFolderPath/js/modernizer-2.0.6.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#whatsthis').mouseover(function(){
        tooltip.show('Tooltip text goes here');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        tooltip.hide();
    });

    $('#printthis').mouseover(function(){
        tooltip.show('&lt;strong&gt;Print&lt;/strong&gt;');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        tooltip.hide();
    }).click(function(){
        printCalendar();
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- container start --> 
    <div id="container">

        <!-- header start --> 
        <header>
            <figure>
                <img src="headerImg.png" width="600" height="100" alt="header image">
            </figure>
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
            <nav>
                <!-- header code goes here - this is actually an include file -->
            </nav>
        </header>       
        <!-- header end -->

        <nav>
            <!-- primary navigation start -->
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
            test
            <!-- primary navigation end -->
        </nav>

        <!-- Application Name start -->
        <div id="applicationName">mySchedule <a href="#" id="whatsthis"><img src="images/what-this.png" width="21" height="21" alt=""></a>
            <!-- breadcrumbs start --> 
            <nav>
                <div id="breadcrumbs">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#MyConnections">Home</a></li>
                        <li>&rarr;</li>
                        <li><a href="#Exhibitors">mySchedule</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- breadcrumbs end --> 
        </div>
        <!-- Application Name end -->

        <!-- Features Toolbar start -->
        <div id="features" class="right">
            <div class="featuresAddOn"> <a href="#" id="printthis">Print mySchedule</a></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Features Toolbar end -->

        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div> 

        <!-- Left Side Bar start -->
        <div class="left">
            <nav>
                <!-- Application Navigation start -->
                <div id="appMenuContainer">
                    <div class="appMenu">
                        <h4 class="firstitem"><a href="/jsp/Myclients/Myclients.jsp?action=ClientMyMatchTab">Client Matching</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="appMenu">
                        <h4 id="MyClient" class="menuitem header"><span><a href="/jsp/Myclients/Myclients.jsp">MyClients</a></span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="appMenu">
                        <h4 id="MySched" class="menuitem header"> <span><a style ="cursor:default">MySchedule</a></span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="appMenu">
                        <h4 id="MyHel" class="menuitem lastitem"> <span><a href="/jsp/Myclients/help.jsp">Help</a></span></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Application Navigation end -->
            <nav>

            <!-- Alert Box start -->
            <aside>
                <div id="AlertBox" class="margin-bottom margin-top">
                    <div class="title">Alert</div>
                    <div class="contentAlert lastItem"> You have <span class="count New_Time">0</span> New Time Proposed Notifications. </div>
                </div>
            </aside>
            <!-- Alert Box ends -->
        </div>
        <!-- Left Side Bar end -->

        <section>
            <!-- Content -->
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </section>

        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>
    <!-- container end --> 

    <footer>
        © MyCompany, Inc. 2011
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

- Among the requirements of the project are that the website use HTML5, and support IE7, IE8, and IE9.
- I have more than one nav. **Do each of these require an id?**
- This is one page of several. The content on all of the pages appears within the div id="calendar" tag. This is dynamically replaced depending on the client. This page looks like a calendar/schedule, for which clients can set appointments.
- I encased the alert box underneath the left side navigation in aside tags. The alert box content is related to the calendar content - it alerts a client if an appointment has been set on the calendar - but wouldn't make sense if it stood on it's own. **Is this use of the aside tag correct in this instance?**
- Regarding the header and footer, previously I had divs that had styles
  attached to them. Since I removed them, I'll now add the styles to the
  header and footer tags. **Is that the correct way to do this? If not, where do the styles go?**

BTW, I'm a web development contractor brought in on this project. So I'm basically updating existing code.

Thanks.

Stephen

Answer (score 2):

- give the site heading in a `h1` (probably in `header`); if the "headerImg.png" is your site name/logo, enclose it in `h1` instead (and give the site name in `alt`)
- if your "headerImg.png" is a typical site header image, you shouldn't use `figure`
- `<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>` is no good style. You can probably use CSS instead.
- it's not clear to me why you have one `nav` inside of `header` *and* one after. Is the one in `header` not for major navigation of the site? Then you shouldn't use `nav` for it
- `<li>&rarr;</li>`: don't add this on its own `li` (better use CSS for it)
- `<div class="title">Alert</div>`: use a heading instead (you can use `h1` here)
- you could enclose "© MyCompany, Inc. 2011" in a `small` element (inside of `footer`)

Is "applicationName" some kind of (main) content on the page? In this case you should give a heading here and/or enclose it in a sectioning element (`section` resp. `article`). Otherwise the Left Side Bar `nav` would be in the scope of the whole page.

Because your `aside` is related to the main content in `section`, the `aside` should be inside of that `section`. At the moment it is related to the whole page.

---

> I have more than one nav. Do each of these require an id?

You don't *have* to use an `id` for `nav`. Only use it if you need/want page anchors (so users can jump to a certain place).

> Regarding the header and footer, previously I had divs that had styles attached to them. Since I removed them, I'll now add the styles to the header and footer tags. Is that the correct way to do this? If not, where do the styles go?

Yes, you can (and probably should) style the elements directly. Only use `div` for styling if you need to group several elements.